# ¿Cómo puedo hacer más corto este código?

Tags: c#

Bueno estoy empezando a programar en C# y quiero aprender cosas nuevas,
estoy haciendo un programa para mi institución y quiero hacerlo un poco más corto porque como está lo veo muy largo y como es mi primer proyecto por así decirlo, no me está quedando mal, pero creo que le hace falta algo:

```
public partial class promedio : Form
{
    double nn, nn2, nn3, nn4, nn5, nt, pr;
    private void btnc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        StreamReader leer = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt");   
        StreamReader leer2 = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text2.txt");
        StreamReader leer3 = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text3.txt");
        StreamReader leer4 = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text4.txt");
        StreamReader leer5 = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text5.txt");
        StreamReader leer6 = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text6.txt");
        StreamReader leer7 = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text7.txt");
        StreamReader leer8 = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text8.txt");
        StreamReader leer9 = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text9.txt");
        StreamReader leer10 = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text10.txt");
        StreamReader leer11 = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text11.txt");
        StreamReader leer1 = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text1.txt");
        StreamReader leer12 = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text12.txt");
        string contenido = null;
        string contenido1 = null;
        string contenido2 = null;
        string contenido3 = null;
        string contenido4 = null;
        string contenido5 = null;
        string contenido6 = null;
        string contenido7 = null;
        string contenido8 = null;
        string contenido9 = null;
        string contenido10 = null;
        string contenido11 = null;
        string contenido12 = null;
        while ((contenido = leer.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            pantalla.Text = contenido.ToString();      
        }
        while ((contenido1 = leer1.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            n1.Text = contenido1.ToString();
        }
        while ((contenido2 = leer2.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            n2.Text = contenido2.ToString();
        }
        while ((contenido3 = leer3.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            n3.Text = contenido3.ToString();
        }
        while ((contenido4 = leer4.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            n4.Text = contenido4.ToString();
        }
        while ((contenido5 = leer5.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            n5.Text = contenido5.ToString();
        }
        while ((contenido6 = leer6.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            pantalla2.Text = contenido6.ToString();
        }
        while((contenido7 = leer7.ReadLine()) != null)
        {  
            checkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
        }
        while ((contenido8 = leer8.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            na.Text = contenido8.ToString();
        }
        while ((contenido9 = leer9.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            es.Text = contenido9.ToString();
        }
        while ((contenido10 = leer10.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            nl.Text = contenido10.ToString();
        }
        while ((contenido11 = leer11.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            sc.Text = contenido11.ToString();
        }
        while ((contenido12 = leer12.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            porcentage.Text = contenido12.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btnguardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter escrito = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt");
        StreamWriter escrito1 = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text1.txt");
        StreamWriter escrito2 = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text2.txt");
        StreamWriter escrito3 = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text3.txt");
        StreamWriter escrito4 = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text4.txt");
        StreamWriter escrito5 = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text5.txt");
        StreamWriter escrito6 = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text6.txt");
        StreamWriter escrito7 = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text7.txt");
        StreamWriter escrito8 = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text8.txt");
        StreamWriter escrito9 = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text9.txt");
        StreamWriter escrito10 = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text10.txt");
        StreamWriter escrito11 = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text11.txt");
        StreamWriter escrito12 = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text12.txt");

        string contenido = pantalla.Text;
        string contenido1 = n1.Text;
        string contenido2 = n2.Text;
        string contenido3 = n3.Text;
        string contenido4 = n4.Text;
        string contenido5 = n5.Text;
        string contenido6 = pantalla2.Text;
        bool contenido7 = checkBox1.Checked;
        string contenido8 = na.Text;
        string contenido9 = es.Text;
        string contenido10 = nl.Text;
        string contenido11 = sc.Text;
        string contenido12 = porcentage.Text;

        escrito.Write(contenido);
        escrito1.Write(contenido1);
        escrito2.Write(contenido2);
        escrito3.Write(contenido3);
        escrito4.Write(contenido4);
        escrito5.Write(contenido5);
        escrito6.Write(contenido6);
        escrito7.Write(contenido7);
        escrito8.Write(contenido8);
        escrito9.Write(contenido9);
        escrito10.Write(contenido10);
        escrito11.Write(contenido11);
        escrito12.Write(contenido12);
        escrito.Flush();
        escrito.Close();
        escrito1.Flush();
        escrito2.Close();
        escrito3.Flush();
        escrito3.Close();
        escrito4.Flush();
        escrito4.Close();
        escrito5.Flush();
        escrito5.Close();
        escrito6.Flush();
        escrito6.Close();
        escrito7.Flush();
        escrito7.Close();
        escrito8.Flush();
        escrito8.Close();
        escrito9.Flush();
        escrito9.Close();
        escrito10.Flush();
        escrito10.Close();
        escrito11.Flush();
        escrito11.Close();
        escrito12.Flush();
        escrito12.Close();
        pantalla.Text = "";
        pantalla2.Text = "";
        n1.Text = "";
        n2.Text = "";
        n3.Text = "";
        n4.Text = "";
        n5.Text = "";
        na.Text = "";
        sc.Text = "";
        es.Text = "";
        nl.Text = "";
        porcentage.Text = "";
        checkBox1.Checked = false;
        MessageBox.Show("guardado correctamente","Guardar");
    }

    public promedio()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double numero1 = Convert.ToDouble(n1.Text);
        double numero2 = Convert.ToDouble(n2.Text);
        double numero3 = Convert.ToDouble(n3.Text);
        double numero4 = Convert.ToDouble(n4.Text);
        double numero5 = Convert.ToDouble(n5.Text);

        nn = Convert.ToDouble(numero1) * 0.35;
        nn2 = Convert.ToDouble(numero2) * 0.10;
        nn3 = Convert.ToDouble(numero3) * 0.25;
        nn4 = Convert.ToDouble(numero4) * 0.05;
        nn5 = Convert.ToDouble(numero5) * 0.40;

        nt = nn + nn2 + nn3 + nn4 + nn5 / 4;

        pr = (35 * nt)/100 ;

        porcentage.Text = pr.ToString();
        pantalla.Text = nt.ToString();

        if (nt <= 6.49 )
        {
            if (nt == 5)
            {
                string b = "Bueno";
                pantalla2.Text = b;
            }

            if (nt == 4)
            {
                string r = "Regular";
                pantalla2.Text = r;
            }

            if (nt == 3)
            {
                string r = "Regular";
                pantalla2.Text = r;
            }
            if (nt == 2)
            {
                string nb = "No Tan Bueno";
                pantalla2.Text = nb;
            }
            if (nt == 1)
            {
                string nb = "No Tan Bueno";
                pantalla2.Text = nb;
            }
            checkBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Checked; 
        }

        if (nt >= 6.50)
        {
            if (nt == 10)
            {
                string exelente = "exelente";
                pantalla2.Text = exelente;
            }
            if (nt == 9)
            {
                string  exelente = "exelente";
                pantalla2.Text = exelente;  
            }
            if (nt == 7)
            {
                string mb = "Muy Bueno";
                pantalla2.Text = mb;
            }
            if (nt == 8)
            {
                string mb = "Muy Bueno";
                pantalla2.Text = mb;
            }
            if (nt == 6)
            {
                string b = "Bueno";
                pantalla2.Text = b;
            }
            checkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
        }
    }
}
```

Sobre todo no quiero crear tantos archivos *txt*.

Algún consejo y díganme qué tan bueno está el código.

Comment: Hola Abdiel bienvenido a [es.so], para que tu pregunta obtenga mayor atención, te sugiero poner aquellos detalles que harán tu pregunta más interesante, por ejemplo, ¿para qué funciona el código que tienes actualmente y cuál es el resultado esperado? Además considera tomar el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y revisar la ayuda para [ crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok tomare en cuenta tu comentario y gracias

Comment: Edité tu pregunta quitando los saltos de línea innecesarios, espero que eso no llegue a entorpecer lo que deseas transmitir. Ahora, me queda una duda, el código que muestras actualmente ¿qué hace o cuál es su objetivo?

Comment: es un codigo simple y como estoy empesando a programar en c# todavia me hace falta mucho que aprender, pues lo que hace el que toma el resultado de las notas (ej laboratorios, examenes, tareas etc) las suma da el resultado y si paso el periodo o no y el porcentage de la nota tambien la conducta del alumno

Comment: Utiliza `StreamReader[] leer` y `string[] contenido`,es decir,arrays en lugar de variables individuales. De esa manera podras leer los datos etc.. utilizando bucles `for`y `foreach`

Comment: Hola, yo que tu empezaria por leerme un buen libro de C# para tener una idea global de lo que se puede hacer y como hacerlo, te recomiento +6.0+in+a+Nutshell y Apress.C.7th. En tu caso con un array te quedaria todo mas elegante y de facil mantinimiento.

Answer (score 3):

Sin entrar en si el código esta mejor o peor hecho, en lineas generales, lo mejor es que cuando veas procesos repetitivos los metas en un método. Por ejemplo:

```
private String leerDeFichero(fichero) {

    StreamReader leer = File.OpenText(fichero);
    String linea;
    String resultado;
    while ((linea = leer.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        resultado+=linea;
    }

    return resultado:
}
```

Y luego ya solo invocarlos uno a uno:

```
string contenido = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt");   
string contenido1 = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text2.txt");
string contenido2 = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text3.txt");
......
```

Esto es mejor de cara a resolver y detectar errores y ayuda muchísimo a la claridad del código.

La idea es que cuando veas una funcionalidad muy clara y concreta, la encapsules en un método o una clase (según la necesidad). Pero para no liarte mucho, con el caso que tienes, creo que solo con que metas parte del código en métodos vas a ganar mucho.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: ok gracias compañero

Comment: Gracias Abdiel!!!!, me alegra haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar `Array` o `List` para guardar los datos en vez de una variable para cada dato. Por otra parte no necesitas declarar una variable de contenido para cada bucle con definir una te valdría. Por otra parte veo que los archivos que lees/escribes son los mismos por lo que podrías guardar la ruta en una variable fuera de las funciones por ejemplo un código más simplificado sería así:

```
private List<KeyValuePair<string, Control>> lista = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Control>>();  
private void CargarLista()
{
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Control>("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt", pantalla));
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Control>("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt1", n1));
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Control>("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt2", n2));
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Control>("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt3", n3));
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Control>("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt4", n4));
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Control>("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt5", n5));
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Control>("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt6", pantalla2));
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Control>("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt7", checkBox1));
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Control>("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt8", na));
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Control>("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt9", es));
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Control>("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt10", nl));
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Control>("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt11", sc));
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Control>("C:\\Users\\JAR\\Desktop\\proyect\\guardar\\text.txt12", porcentage));
}


private void btnguardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Control> pair in lista)
    {
        using (StreamWriter strWritter = File.CreateText(pair.Key))
        {
            strWritter.Write(pair.Value.Text);
            strWritter.Close();
            strWritter.Dispose();
        }
        if (pair.Value.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
        {
            ((CheckBox)(pair.Value)).Checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            pair.Value.Text = "";
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("guardado correctamente", "Guardar");      }



   private void btnc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Control> pair in lista)
    {
        using (StreamReader strReadder = File.OpenText(pair.Key))
        {           
            while ((contenido = leer.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if(typeof(CheckBox) == pair.Value.GetType())
                    ((CheckBox)lista.Value).CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                else
                    lista.Value.Text = contenido;                        
            }       
        }       

    }
}
```

Comentar además varias cosas, cuando lees los ficheros pueden tener más de una linea? ya que si es así y quieres poner todo el texto dentro de los controles deberás usar `lista.Value.Text += contenido;`  en vez de `lista.Value.Text = contenido;`  También si quieres hacer algo personalizado para algún otro tipo de control que no sea CheckBox deberás añadir su lógica correspondiente. Finalmente comentar que para cargar al lista hay que llamar a `CargarLista()` al menos una vez por ejemplo cuando se carga el formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto mis consejos:

1. Usa  literal de cadena textual "Verbatim Stirings" te permite tener código mas legible el el caso de rutas archivos o cadenas con secuencias de escape.

   File.CreateText("C:\Users\JAR\Desktop\proyect\guardar\text.txt");
   File.CreateText(@"C:\Users\JAR\Desktop\proyect\guardar\text.txt");
2. Elimina el método Flush. El método flush se ejecuta automáticamente cuando usas el método Close(). Nunca uses `s.Flush(); s.Close();`
3. Considera usar el método estático File.WriteAllLine(). Te ahorras muchas linas

   File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\JAR\Desktop\proyect\guardar\", pantalla.Text);
   File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\JAR\Desktop\proyect\guardar\", n1.Text);

Saludos

Comment: ok gracias lo probare